# where do I get customerId when executing google developers "try it" api explorer?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-directory-api

I want to try out some API commands using the "try it" api explorer in Google Developers Documenatation, in particular, listing the schemas associated with my Google Apps Education account.

I have tried using the domain name, as well as the client ID found on the API Manager credentials page to no avail, as well as my own email address... where in the user interface(s) can I find it? Knowing I have the right thing will sure speed things up :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way I found was to

- create an apps script project
- enable the project resources (Resources > Advanced Google Services)
- enable the Admin SDK for the project in the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com)
- get a user and show value with

  var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get('robf@austinmontessori.org');
  Logger.log( user.customerId );

The number is ?the same for all users in the domain and looks something like "C02cathat"

Comment: so you mean the customer id is the same for all the emails/users in the domain? Would it not be unique for each email/user?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Users-Get section on their site and execute on a user email address. This will give you the CustomerId and all other information on the user.